# How do you print out the the value of input text that you put in? Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Right now, this is my code. What I want to do is replace the #'s with the values corresponding to the values of the input text. 
So instead of something like "Pushup # time / # seconds", I want something like "Pushup 40 times / 3 seconds".

My URL changes to the values

```
settings.html?pushupQuantity=30&pushupTime=2&pullupQuantity=40&pullupTime=4
```

I'm not that good with HTML and JavaScript and can't figure out a way to do this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="jumbotron text text-center">
  <h1>Settings</h1>
</div>
<div class="container justify-content-center">

  <h2>Pushup # time / # seconds</h2>
  <h2>Pullup # time / # seconds</h2>
  <h2>Squats # time / # seconds</h2>

  <form action='./settings.html'>
    <h1>Pushups</h1>
    <img src="https://media.tenor.com/images/28fecfea6b4a7c36c7e45c76fe86b3b8/tenor.gif" alt="pushup gif" /><br>
    <label for="pushupQuantity">Pushup Quantity: </label>
    <input type="text" id="pushupQuantity" name="pushupQuantity" value="30"><br>
    <label for="pushupTime">Seconds in between: </label>
    <input type="text" id="pushupTime" name="pushupTime" value="2"><br>
    <hr>
    <h1>Pullups</h1>
    <img src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/FailingSlushyBoa-size_restricted.gif" alt="pullup gif" /><br>
    <label for="pullupQuantity">Pullup Quantity: </label>
    <input type="text" id="pullupQuantity" name="pullupQuantity" value="40"><br>
    <label for="pullupTime">Seconds in between: </label>
    <input type="text" id="pullupTime" name="pullupTime" value="4"><br>
    <hr>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: To get the parameter from the  query string you refer:

https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript

However, in which context you want to replace the # to the parameter?
In page load? Or a button click?

Comment: Check out this simple example.  http://jsfiddle.net/CodingWith/vmy24

Comment: Thank you very much! As to which context I wanted to replace it, it was page load. I should have clarified it on my question but I figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create function for each activity, which will get called on specific activity panel gets updated. And just update those value into your page by identifying output fields

Updated code for PushUp Activity.`

```js
function calculatePushup(){
            document.getElementById("pushupQuantityLabel").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pushupQuantity").value;
            document.getElementById("pushupTimeLabel").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pushupTime").value;
        }
        // update with default values when page load for the first time.
        calculatePushup();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Settings</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script>
      
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron text text-center">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container justify-content-center">
        
        <h2>Pushup <span id="pushupQuantityLabel">#</span> time / <span id="pushupTimeLabel">#</span> seconds</h2>
        <h2>Pullup # time / # seconds</h2>
        <h2>Squats # time / # seconds</h2>

        <form action='./settings.html'>
            <h1>Pushups</h1>
            <img src="https://media.tenor.com/images/28fecfea6b4a7c36c7e45c76fe86b3b8/tenor.gif" alt="pushup gif" /><br>
            <label for="pushupQuantity">Pushup Quantity: </label>
            <input type="text" id="pushupQuantity" name="pushupQuantity" value="30" onkeyup="calculatePushup()"/><br>
            <label for="pushupTime">Seconds in between: </label>
            <input type="text" id="pushupTime" name="pushupTime" value="2"  onkeyup="calculatePushup()"/><br>
            <hr>
            <h1>Pullups</h1>
            <img src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/FailingSlushyBoa-size_restricted.gif" alt="pullup gif" /><br>
            <label for="pullupQuantity">Pullup Quantity: </label>
            <input type="text" id="pullupQuantity" name="pullupQuantity" value="40"><br>
            <label for="pullupTime">Seconds in between: </label>
            <input type="text" id="pullupTime" name="pullupTime" value="4"><br>
            <hr>
            <input class="btn btn-primary"type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

in same manner you can add functionality for other activity. Just add event to fields on which you want to call function. Create function which will fetch fields value and then display them into output fields by identifying with their respective id's.